# GWT 2.4 Data Grid -- Horizontal Scroll Bar obscures last row

Tags: gwt, datagrid, scrollbar

The new DataGrid widget in GWT 2.4 automatically generates a horizontal scroll bar when the display viewport for the table is not as wide as the table itself, and a vertical scrollbar for the vertical case.  Fine so far.  But I have found that the scrollbar obscures the last row of the table.  There is no filler space after the last row to allow you to vertically scroll a bit farther to let the last row completely enter the viewing space.  That filler bar ought to be at least as tall as the scrollbar, and preferably a bit taller.

Any ideas for a work-around?  I don't want to add empty data rows since these represents real rows in a real database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that if you select a row (even with NoSelectionModel, there is a "select" where the row turns pale yellow), then tap the up and down arrows on the keyboard, the DataGrid rolls up and down, including pulling any rows obscured by the header or footer or horizontal scrollbar entirely into view.

Good to know.  Will have to train the users on that little trick.